# How to handle same webelement having different locator in different browser in python

Tags: python, selenium, cross-browser

eg: I have a textbox "ABC" in application "XYZ".
In chrome when I give the css selector as "input[@id='abc_box']", then it locates the element but when same locator I give for Firefox then it gives NosuchElementException because this textbox is half obscured by some other element when opened in firefox. So to locate it I use some other locator like "input[@name='something']".

Now 1 way I can handle it is using if else. But this is not good as if there are 100 such locators and I have 5 to 6 browsers then It will be huge.

In Java, I think @FindAll will be a good solution.

Similarly in Python, I want a better solution to it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and with relevant HTML?

Comment: @KunduK : Since this is just an example(I cannot share it from my project) so I am not providing any real time html. I tried to search for such real time situation but I am not able to find.